# Does the formula v=Ldi/dt apply to materials with zero resistence, such as superconductors?

Tags: current, resistance, induction, superconductors

I've been trying to find information about the formula \$ v = L \cdot \frac{di}{dt} \$, it seem to have something to do with voltage drop, and I know voltage drop is caused by resistance, so would a material with zero resistance still have weaker levels of induction with higher frequencies of changing current?

Comment: Impedance, not resistance. Reactance in this case.

Comment: Are you asking what is "resisting" to the current in inductors? Nothing. The magnetic field is resisting to the *change* of the current (hence the derivative).

Comment: You might also consider the time constant- L/R and what happens to that when R is zero.

Comment: **and I know voltage drop is caused by resistance**  - One component of voltage drop is caused by resistance. There are other components to voltage drop, one of those is Ldi/dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Actually, for an inductor,

\$ v = L \frac{di}{dt} + Ri \$

R is the resistance of the wire in your inductor. If you use a superconductor, it would be zero. The first part of this equation models a theoretically perfect inductor (ie, superconducting, like all inductors in spice simulation unless you specify its resistance in the spice model). The second part models its resistance. In an equivalent circuit, the inductance and its resistive part can be put in series, this does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula is the basic law on how inductors behave in electric circuits. Actually it's derived from a relation between magnetic and electric field, more specificly from the one that states how strong electric field is caused if magnetic field changes. That law is as valid in all materials and in the empty space.

Conclusion: Your formula is as valid in all circuits, no matter if some parts of it are superconductive.

Answer (score 1):

Given that superconductors have  the lowest resistance, this does not affect their inductance.

Inductance is controlled by the geometric ratio of the conductor Length/Width and the relative permeability of any surrounding magnetic material.

The voltage drop you may have heard about could be due to the reactive impedance at some f which has nothing to due with real loss, from IR drop.

\$Z_L=\omega L\$

Then if a  load R, is a applied to a superconducting source with some voltage and frequency , the load will see \$V_o=V_i\dfrac{R}{\omega L+R}\$

The basic transient behavior of inductors is as you stated.
\$V_L=L dI/dt\$

However the voltage change at a switch, relative to 0V, when released, will be a pulse in **the opposite polarity** of the voltage when current is applied.    i.e. A high side switch opening results in a sudden drop in current or a negative ΔI thus a large negative spike is produced.  So a Low-side DC switch releases a +ve spike and High-side switch to L releases a large -ve spike.

The other important formula is how much energy is stored in an inductor depends on the current.  This is the amount of energy dissipated in the arc of a switch or FET-internal clamp diode when turning off an Inductive load.

\$E=\frac{1}{2}LI^2\$  [J=Joules = Watt-seconds]